# Using SwingWorker for client/server application stops handling requests after 10 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a server project and a client project (2 clients, a customer and an admin, from the customer GUI/Frame you can go to the admin GUI and move between GUIs as needed).

I have a button on each GUI/Frame which just sends a String to the server when it's clicked. I'm printing out the threads that are being created and I know that SwingWorkers Thread pool defaults to 10, and then it starts reusing threads.

I've noticed that once the created Threads hit 10, then the buttons to send requests to the server do not seem to send any data because the Thread pool is fully occupied.

I wanted to know how I can prevent this so a user can switch between the GUIs for x amount of time.

--
**Server**

```
public class Testserver {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket client;
    private final int PORT = 5432;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;

    public Testserver() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Testserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    private void listenForClients() {
        try {

            while (true) {
                client = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("client connected");
                objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                processClient();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Testserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Testserver().listenForClients();
        });
    }

    private void processClient() {
        SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

                do {
                    try {
                        String messageFromClient = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
                        
                        System.out.println("[CLIENT] " + messageFromClient);

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Testserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Testserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                    }
                } while (true);

            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }

}
```

---

**Customer Client**

```
public class CustomerGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    private Socket server;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    private JButton btnAdminGUI,btnAddCustomer;
    private final int PORT = 5432;
    
    public CustomerGUI()  {
        
        btnAdminGUI = new JButton("Go to Admin GUI");
        btnAddCustomer = new JButton("Add customer");
               
        try {
            server = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
            System.out.println("Connected to server");
            
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        
        btnAdminGUI.addActionListener(this);
        btnAddCustomer.addActionListener(this);

    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new CustomerGUI().setGUI();
        });
    }
    
    public void setGUI() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        add(btnAdminGUI);
        add(btnAddCustomer);
        setSize(300, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(e.getSource() == btnAdminGUI) {
           new AdminGUI().setGUI();  
           dispose();
            
       } else if(e.getSource() == btnAddCustomer) {
           try {
               objectOutputStream.writeObject("Added a customer");
               objectOutputStream.flush();
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(AdminGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

---

**Admin Client(Pretty much the same as Customer)**

```
public class AdminGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    private Socket server;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    private JButton btnCustomerGUI, btnAddAdmin;
    private final int PORT = 5432;
    
    public AdminGUI()  {
        
        btnCustomerGUI = new JButton("Go to Customer GUI");
        btnAddAdmin = new JButton("Add admin");
        try {
            server = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
            System.out.println("Connected to server");
            
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        
        btnAddAdmin.addActionListener(this);
        btnCustomerGUI.addActionListener(this);

    }
   
    
    public void setGUI() {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        add(btnCustomerGUI);
        add(btnAddAdmin);
        setSize(300, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(e.getSource() == btnCustomerGUI) {
           new CustomerGUI().setGUI();  
           dispose();
       } else if(e.getSource() == btnAddAdmin) {
           try {
               objectOutputStream.writeObject("Added an admin");
               objectOutputStream.flush();
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(AdminGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Updated working method code using FixedThreadPool

```java
private void processClient() {

        System.out.println("cores: " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

        executor.execute(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            do {
                try {
                    String messageFromClient = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();

                    System.out.println("[CLIENT] " + messageFromClient);

                    if (messageFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
                        System.out.println("closed connection to " + client);
                        closeConnections();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException in process client: " + ex.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("Exception in process client: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            } while (true);

        });
executor.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Q: Why use `SwingWorker`? Why not use `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead? You don't appear to be using any of the special SwingWorker features (e.g., the property-change listeners list.) `ThreadPoolExecutor` gives you control over how many threads are in the pool.

Comment: Although your code is pretty good quality, I would second what @SolomonSlow says. For another thing, you don't want one ```SwingWorker``` per client. There's another problem too: you're reassigning each client's streams to instance variables. That's wrong: you need separate stream instances for every client

Comment: @SolomonSlow,so I should be using a Thread Pool executor with lets say 100 threads which I think should be enough before the user closes the program?

Comment: @g00se Thanks, i didnt notice that until now lol. Also, in my servers while loop just after accepting the clients request, i create the object streams, should this not be created once for the lifetime of the program? If that's the case, how could i initialize the streams once a client connects besides having it in the while loop as that would just initialize the streams over and over

Comment: Essentially you need a `Client` class that's initialised with the `Socket` got from the server. Each will encapsulate its own streams

Comment: I've never used `SwingWorker`. I don't know whether or how you can control the number of SwingWorker worker threads, but you _can_ control the number of `ThreadPoolExecutor` threads, and given that your problem is, not enough threads... I _personally_  would go with the ThreadPoolExecutor. That's all.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using a Fixed Thread Pool and it's working as expected now.

Comment: It might be nice to post that code

Comment: Did it now, thanks again